# Can I use a TypeScript type with io-ts?

Tags: typescript, types, io-ts-library

I am working on validating API responses using [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts).

I have already defined the following type in regular TypeScript:

```js
export type Group = {
   id: number;
   name: string;
}
```

And I want to use this type in io-ts like this:

```js
const UploadedSearch = t.type({
    id: t.number,
    title: t.string,
    groups: t.array(Group),
});
```

But I get the following error.

```
TS2693: 'Group' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

Is there any way to use `Group` in the io-ts code?

Comment: you must make a new type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment on your question already mentioned this but to illustrate how to use `io-ts` not to repeat yourself, you can say:

```js
const GroupCodec = t.type({
  id: t.number,
  name: t.string,
});
// Will be equivalent to your group type, so no need to repeat yourself.
export type Group = t.TypeOf<typeof GroupCodec>;

const UploadedSearch = t.type({
  id: t.number,
  title: t.string,
  groups: t.array(GroupCodec),
});
```